# Re-use existing python script to run as spark job rather than making pyspark code changes

Tags: python, apache-spark

We are planning to migrate to Spark. Is there a way to use my existing Python code/script to run locally directly in Spark (without making any Pyspark changes in the code)?

I am trying to use the existing Python scripts to be run in the Spark cluster.

Comment: Yes, it is possible. Be aware that any additional packages need to be installed on the spark cluster beforehand.

Comment: Hi Péter Szilvási, Thank you for the response. Could you please provide the steps or any sample code wherein this is being done. In our existing script we are using python native libraries panda, numpy etc. I want this script to be called as is from spark job. Please help with the sample code or any reference..Would be a great help

Comment: Yes sure. Here are some examples where data frames are used: https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.2.0/api/python/getting_started/quickstart_ps.html includes cleaning/grouping/plotting and the https://sparkbyexamples.com/pyspark/pandas-api-on-apache-spark-pyspark/ contains conversion/filtering/renaming. If you are using PySpark version > 3.2, you can import with `import pyspark.pandas as ps`.

Comment: At the moment, I can not reach any Spark (Databricks) cluster. However, I can provide some example on Monday if you wish. Please let me know!

Comment: Hi Peter, Thanks a ton for getting back with the resolution... Yeah please do share some examples as this would really be a great help for me to refer and replicate

Answer (score 1):

### Connect to Spark Cluster

I am not very familiar about Spark cluster outside of Databricks so my answer will be limited to it. However, here is a documentation about connecting to Spark Server: https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/getting_started/quickstart_connect.html

In a nutshell, you need to setup a Spark Server on the cluster and then connect to it through a Spark Client.

### Connect to Databricks via VSCode

The prerequisites are a spark compute cluster, the necessary packages installed on the cluster, and an IDE to connect to the remote cluster. I have followed the [VSCode extension for Databricks](https://docs.databricks.com/en/dev-tools/vscode-ext/tutorial.html) guide to execute local Python scripts to the remote Databricks cluster.

Once you have installed the VSCode extension, authenticate to your remote cluster:

1. Click the Databricks logo on the sidebar.
2. Click on <kbd>Configure Databricks</kbd> pane.
3. Enter the Databricks host URL then select the **OAuth** authentication option.

After these steps, you will have `.databricks`, and `.vscode` folders which contain the configurations.

### Running Python scripts

I created a `demo.py` Python script without using any packages for testing purposes:

```py
def fizz_buzz(n):
    if n % 3 == 0 and n % 5 == 0:
        print("FizzBuzz")
    elif n % 3 == 0:
        print("Fizz")
    elif n % 5 == 0:
        print("Buzz")
    else:
        print(n)

fizz_buzz(5)
fizz_buzz(15)
fizz_buzz(3)
```

The next step is to select the appropriate cluster and start it. It could take some time. Then, **Snyc Destination** to upload the demo file.

> Note: You shall create a `.gitignore` file so the virtual environment and other package folders will not uploaded to your workspace.

If you configured everything successfully, you will get an output like this:

[image: databricks configuration]

You can see that the cluster state is `RUNNING` and the local folder was synced at `/Users/<your_user_name>/.ide` folders.

The final step is to right-click on your Python script file, and then click **Upload and Run File on Databricks** option. The running output is the following:

```
2/28/2024, 10:08:16 AM - Creating execution context on cluster 0406-115408-8gcdjobk ...
2/28/2024, 10:08:34 AM - Synchronizing code to /Users/peter.szilvasi@zf.com/.ide/databricks-pandas-73ef1873 ...
2/28/2024, 10:08:34 AM - Running demo.py ...

Buzz
FizzBuzz
Fizz
2/28/2024, 10:08:39 AM - Done (took 22693ms)
```

If you wish, you can run the script file as a job by clicking on **Run File as Workflow on Databricks** option.

### Using packages

If you have packages (e.g. `pandas`), you need to install it on the cluster before. In Databricks, navigate to **Compute** > Select your cluster > Go to the **Libraries** tab > Click on **Install new** button. With this, you can utilize packages in your Python scripts:

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({"col1": [1, 2, 3], "col2": [4, 5, 6]})
print(df)
```

As before, right-click on the script file and **Upload and Run File on Databricks** option which gives this output:

```
2/28/2024, 10:11:18 AM - Creating execution context on cluster 0406-115408-8gcdjobk ...
2/28/2024, 10:11:27 AM - Synchronizing code to /Users/<your_user_name>/.ide/databricks-pandas-73ef1873 ...
2/28/2024, 10:11:27 AM - Running pandas_demo.py ...

col1  col2
0     1     4
1     2     5
2     3     6
2/28/2024, 10:11:30 AM - Done (took 11827ms)
```

> Note: Do not forget to terminate the cluster after you have finished using it. Save the planet! :)

Comment: Hi Peter, Thank you so much for your detailed response but I would need some more clarity as unable to comprehend much here, new to this setup too..What I want here is to run my python (enormous code- non pyspark code) on spark cluster...Is it possible to do without making any/slight changes to the code?

Comment: Yes, it is possible. I managed to run only Python code in the examples. Since I have access only to Databricks (which is running under a spark cluster), my answer is limited to Databricks. But in general, 1) you need to connect to the spark cluster then 2) install the necessary packages on it so that 3) you can run Python code in that spark session. I have updated the answer about connecting to Spark server.

Comment: Hi Péter Szilvási
Thanks for the response, I did try spark-submit abc.py the script ran but there was nothing shown in SparkWebUI and this did not initiate the spark-shell....P.S. I am using spark on linux server